# Hive Dyanamic Partitioning failing to write partitions to final subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, database-partitioning

I am still new to hive

I have the following table loaded with data

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  col1 string,
  col2 string,
  col3 float,
  col4 float)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

and i want to partition it by col1 string

```
CREATE TABLE table1_partition (
  col2 string,
  col3 float,
  col4 float)
PARTITIONED BY (col1 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I get errors when i run the following

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1_partition PARTITION (col1)
SELECT col2, col3, col4, 
col1 FROM table1;
```

ERROR

```
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2020-03-11 05:23:22,584 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2020-03-11 05:24:22,944 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2020-03-11 05:25:23,122 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local441210382_0001 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://localhost:8080/
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 1858506752 HDFS Write: 1477771205 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I looked into logs file and it seems that the datanodes that should be written to are getting deleted:

```
2020-03-11 05:47:01,916 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DirectoryScanner: BlockPool BP-433273321-127.0.1.1-1583889697525 Total blocks: 14, missing metadata files:0, missing block files:0, missing blocks in memory:0, mismatched blocks:0
```

I also looked in /tmp/hadoop-myuser/dfs/data/current/.../finalised/ as per log, subdir0 - subdir5 have files & some of them are empty.

Please help me understand this issue.

Comment: Try to find failed container log, it would be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Set `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` to `nostrict`, e.g.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict
```

before executing the query. By default hive work in strict mode. From Hive's manual

> In strict mode, the user must specify at least one static partition in case the user accidentally overwrites all partitions, in nonstrict mode all partitions are allowed to be dynamic